# PHP limits output when using JSON_ENCODE

Tags: php, json

Is there any character limit while using PHP. 
I am encoding data written by PHP to JSON using following code :

```
$wc_api = new WC_API_Client( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $store_url );

// Get all products

echo json_encode( $wc_api->get_products(), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
```

But it is giving only first few products. Can any one help me out?

Comment: Dump the result of `$wc_api->get_products()` without converting it to JSON and make sure that the API is actually sending you all products.

Comment: Yes I have checked with API. I used echo json_encode( $wc_api->get_products_count() ); and it is sending me total product count which is correct.